# Google Calendar API and Service Account permission error

Tags: node.js, jwt, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to integrate the Google Calendar API in my app.
So far i've managed to do this:

- Created a new project on Cloud Platform
- Enabled Calendar API
- Added a new service account with role: Owner
- Generated jwt.json
- Granted domain-wide for that service account
- Shared a calendar with that service account (modify rights)
- Enabled in the GSuite the option for everyone out of the organisation to modify the events

Now, my code on node.js looks like this:

```js
const { JWT } = require('google-auth-library');

const client = new JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
);

const url = `https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${keys.project_id}`;
const rest = await client.request({url});
console.log(rest);
```

The error I get is:

**Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
 Error: Insufficient Permission**

Anyone has any ideea? This gets frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

I think that in your script, the endpoint and/or scope might be not correct.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your endpoint of `https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${keys.project_id}` is used.

#### Modified script:

```
const { JWT } = require("google-auth-library");
const keys = require("###");  // Please set the filename of credential file of the service account.

async function main() {
  const calendarId = "ip15lduoirvpitbgc4ppm777ag@group.calendar.google.com";
  const client = new JWT(keys.client_email, null, keys.private_key, [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'  // <--- Modified
  ]);
  const url = `https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${keys.project_id}`;
  const res = await client.request({ url });
  console.log(res.data);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

- In this case, it is required to enable Cloud DNS API at API console. And it is required to pay. Please be careful with this.

  - I thought that the reason of your error message of `Insufficient Permission` might be this.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, as a sample situation, the event list is retrieved from the calendar shared with the service account. If the calendar can be used with the service account, the event list is returned. By this, I think that you can confirm whether the script works.

#### Modified script:

```
const { JWT } = require("google-auth-library");
const keys = require("###");  // Please set the filename of credential file of the service account.

async function main() {
  const calendarId = "###";  // Please set the calendar ID.

  const client = new JWT(keys.client_email, null, keys.private_key, [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
  ]);
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events`;  // <--- Modified
  const res = await client.request({ url });
  console.log(res.data);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you are using `google-auth-library-nodejs` of the latest version.

### Reference:

- [JSON Web Tokens in google-auth-library-nodejs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#json-web-tokens)